# Control Source If statement

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I want access to automatically calculate the output if the entered value is > 0. So I put the following code in the "Control Source" field of a textbox property and it is giving me an error. The Number should be obtained from Text052 and it should output it in Text054.

Here is the code:

```
If Text052.value > 0 then
Text054.value = Val([Text052].[Value])/2
end if
```

Error: "The expression you enetered contains invalid syntax". 
       "You have enetered the operand without the operator"

I am not sure how to write the syntax in the control source field of the text box propety.
Please advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the control source of Text054, try:

```
=IIf([Text052] > 0,[Text052]/2, "N/A")
```

"N/A" can be whatever you need, including null.

Comment: Is there any way to do the following:

Comment: =IIf([DLookup("[Sum_MU]", "6_Provincial", "[BudgetYear] =" & [Combo5] And "[Program_Name] ='" & [Combo7] & "'")] > 0,0, Val(Text18.Value))

Comment: ^What I am trying to say is that if the DLookup value is > 0 then input 0 otherwise put a number from another textbox

Comment: You are really starting to break the rules of SO. You are repeating errors that have been previously discussed and returning to questions that have already been answered with those mistakes.

Comment: Try: `=IIf(Nz(DLookup("[Sum_MU]", "6_Provincial", "[BudgetYear] =" & [Combo5] & " And [Program_Name] ='" & [Combo7] & "'"),0) > 0,0, Text18)`